# Creating and migrating database in sqlx

Tags: rust, actix-web

I am reading the zero to production book, and pages 74-76  of the book talks about how the test function fails when run more than one time because everytime we run `cargo test` the test function runs the app and there is an insert query in the app, so everytime we run the test,  the app gets called and the insert queries are executed and the same value is inserted which causes error due to the unique key constraint. The book provides a solution as 
1.create a new logical database with a unique name
2.run migrations on this database

```
//! tests/health_check.rs
use std::net::TcpListener;
use sqlx::{PgConnection, PgPool, Connection, Executor};
use zero2prod::configuration::{get_configuration, DatabaseSettings};
use zero2prod::startup::run;
use uuid::Uuid;

pub struct TestApp {
    pub address: String,
    pub pool: PgPool,
}

async fn spawn_app() -> TestApp {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:0").expect("failed to bind to the port");
    let port = listener.local_addr().unwrap().port();
    let address = format!("http://127.0.0.1:{}", port);

    let mut configuration = get_configuration().expect("failed to read configuration");
    configuration.database.database_name = Uuid::new_v4().to_string();
    let connection_pool = PgPool::connect(&configuration.database.connection_string()).await.expect("failed to connect to postgres");
    let server = run(listener, connection_pool.clone()).expect("failed to bind to address");
    let _ = tokio::spawn(server);
    TestApp{
        address,
        pool: connection_pool,
    }
}
```

the book then proceeds to add the following changes:

```
//! tests/health_check.rs
let mut configuration = get_configuration().expect("Failed to read configuration.");
configuration.database.database_name = Uuid::new_v4().to_string();
let connection_pool = PgPool::connect(&configuration.database.connection_string())
.await
.expect("Failed to connect to Postgres.");
```

```
//! src/configuration.rs
// [...]
impl DatabaseSettings {
pub fn connection_string(&self) -> String {
    format!(
        "postgres://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}",
        self.username, self.password, self.host, self.port, self.database_name
    )

}
    pub fn connection_string_without_db(&self) -> String {
        format!(
            "postgres://{}:{}@{}:{}",
            self.username, self.password, self.host, self.port
        )
    }
}
```

```
//! tests/health_check.rs
// [...]
use sqlx::{Connection, Executor, PgConnection, PgPool};
use zero2prod::configuration::{get_configuration, DatabaseSettings};
async fn spawn_app() -> TestApp {
// [...]
let mut configuration = get_configuration().expect("Failed to read configuration.");
configuration.database.database_name = Uuid::new_v4().to_string();
let connection_pool = configure_database(&configuration.database).await;
// [...]
}
pub async fn configure_database(config: &DatabaseSettings) -> PgPool {
// Create database
    let mut connection = PgConnection::connect(&config.connection_string_without_db())
        .await
        .expect("Failed to connect to Postgres");
    connection
        .execute(format!(r#"CREATE DATABASE "{}";"#, config.database_name).as_str())
        .await
        .expect("Failed to create database.");
// Migrate database
    let connection_pool = PgPool::connect(&config.connection_string())
        .await
        .expect("Failed to connect to Postgres.");
    sqlx::migrate!("./migrations")
        .run(&connection_pool)
        .await
        .expect("Failed to migrate the database");
    connection_pool
}
```

I can't understand what this last function `configure_database` does and  how adding the function solves the problem

Comment: `configure_database` creates a new database with a random name (because `configuration.database.database_name = Uuid::new_v4().to_string();`) and then runs the tests in this new database, so the tests will always see a pristine DB. Note however that if you don't cleanup on exit, you will wind up with a lot of stale databases on your server…

Answer (score 0):

if he doesn't create a new database and uses the same database, **he won't be able to do full fledged testing as their is data present from its previous test**. I also read that book and he is using docker container for Postgress. Instead of creating a new random database, he can also remove the docker container and create a new one, every time he runs the test, then he can use constant database name. which is bit of headache process if you ask me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).